# Understanding the Powershell Command

Tags: powershell

does anybody know exactly what this means/makes?

```
% {$_.Line.tostring().Split(' ')[4]}
```

**EDIT :**

**This question is Irelevant and does not have a purpose anymore!
it was an internal script mistake!**

Comment: Please do not ask people to [read the documentation to you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Comment: What it "makes" is completely ependent on the input to it

Comment: looks like it gets the output of select-string, splits it on spaces, and gets the (4th) 5th element of the resulting array, try googling it in future, as this is pretty straightforward code.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Absolutely correct. Shaking off the fog still. It would be position 5.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The question is a followup to [his previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139326/1630171).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**%**           Foreach

**{}**          Foreach container

**$_**          This references whatever object was piped in before the vertical bar that was likely preceding the mark percent (foreach) mark.

**.Line**       A hopefully valid property of the piped object ($_)

**ToString()**  Explicit type conversion to a string. (Maybe integers are being parsed.)

**Split()**     Cuts a string on a specified delimiter to create an array from a string. The delimiter here is a space. (' ')

**[4]**         Selecting the contents of the 5th position of that array that was just created. Arrays of course being zero-indexed.